# Angular mat-button-toggle rendering does not bind to ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngmodel

I have been trying to fix a bug where the `mat-button-toggle` element renders as "selected", even though the `ngModel` has a `false` value. And I found something, that at least to me looks strange. Consider a code example:

`.html`

```
<mat-button-toggle 
    [(ngModel)]="myVar" 
    (change)="toggle()"
    ngDefaultControl
    name="myVar">
  TOGGLE ME
</mat-button-toggle>
```

`.ts`

```
myVar = false
toggle() {
    // do nothing!
}
```

**I expected:**

After you click on the button, it does NOT render as "selected" because `myVar` still has `false` value.

**What actually happens:**

The button renders as "selected" disregarding the actual `myVar` value.

I have a feeling I miss some core Angular understanding here that makes me unable to understand why doesn't it work like I expect it to. Can you help me understand what is wrong here?

Comment: don't you get ```Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute``` ?

Comment: I decided to remove `ngDefaultControl` from the question to simplify it, but I'll add it back. The problem still persists though.

Comment: I suspect it should be [(ngModel)]="myVar"

Comment: Do you mean double quotes? If yes, just tried and didn't help. I'll update the question with double quotes for consistency though, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MatButtonToggle does not support angular's two way binding. For Angular two binding to work the component needs to implement `ControlValueAccessor` which MatButtonToggle does not. Instead you can can listen for the event and manually bind it.

```
<mat-button-toggle 
  [checked]="myFlagForButtonToggle" 
  (change)="myFlagForButtonToggle = $event.source.checked">
    Toggle me!
</mat-button-toggle>
```